# reference objects in a vue delaration

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need some help with structure.  In my Vue page I have

```
                 export default { 
    name: 'Member',

    data() {
        return {
                modalImport: false,
                articles: {},
                index: 0                  
        }
    },        
    mounted() {
            } ,
```

And in my template section the HTML looks like:

```
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                        {{index+1}}.
                        <span :id="'status_'+article.uid" class="auto-new"></span>
                        <span :id="'details_' + article.uid">
                            <template v-if="article.authors">{{(article.authors.map(a=>a.name)).join(',')}}.</template>
                            <a v-if="article.title" :href="'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/'+article.uid" target='_blank'>{{article.title}}</a>
                            <template v-if="article.source">{{article.source}}. </template>

                        </span>
                    </div>
```

If I create code that goes and get the data for the object articles it works fine as long as I create the code inside the export default block.  Since the articles can be make up of values I need to have the function run independently and I'll pass in the variables on different button clicks.  Such as

```
          function  getArticles(ID_Values){

          }
```

instead of duplicating the code for each call.  If I create the function outside the block it throws an error saying it does not know what "article" is since it referenced in the function but not declared other than in the default block. I hope that I'm clear I'm new to Vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your function as a [method](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/events.html) in Vue.

```
export default { 
    name: 'Member',

    data() {
        return {
                modalImport: false,
                articles: {},
                index: 0                  
        }
    }, 
    methods: {
       getArticles(ID_Values) {
        //reference to articles as this.articles
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks- I was doing this the first time and I went back to it and added this.getArticles and it worked.  Thanks for the help  Without you helping I would have been on the wrong path for awhile